# scrlttr2 another frombank

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

The `frombank` komavar is perfect. It does everything I want to. But I need another one, since I have to add two bank accounts to the footer in the letter. Is it possible to have another `frombank`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\newkomavar` to define a new variable for the second `frombank`:

```latex
\newkomavar[description]{name}
```

Example:

```latex
\newkomavar[\usekomavar*{frombank}]{secondfrombank}
\setkomavar{secondfrombank}{Someotherbank}
```